# How to Approach Fixing a Roof Leak When Drywall is Rotted Out?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, leak, roof

My parents house has a leak in the roof that hasn't been takan care of for a few years and has pretty much destroyed the drywall in the affected region.

What strategy should I use to repair the leak?

I was considering removing the drywall (In preparation for a California patch) to see where the leak originates from (Possibly with the assistance of a second person with a hose on the roof) and looking for it that way.

I've also considered looking for the leak after the drywall has been removed, and if I can find it without a second person (If it's really obvious), just drilling a very small hole where the origin of the water is and leaving the drill bit sticking out of the roof and using roof caulk to seal it up there. I could patch the drywall later then.

What is the typical procedure for a situation like this?

Picture of the effected region:
[image: Roof Leak]
[image: Roof Leak Close Up]

Comment: $50 says it's leaking around the edge of the skylight, and the damage to the drywall is visible in that location only because there's a joint there.

Comment: @brhans Well, there is tape in the region, so there is a drywall joint there.